# how to make distro from cmake project with ExternalProject module

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a cmake project which depends on other cmake projects which produce dll:

```
include(ExternalProject)
...
set(COMMON_BASE_PROJECT_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../CommonBase)
...
ExternalProject_Add(CommonBaseProject
  SOURCE_DIR ${COMMON_BASE_PROJECT_DIR}
  BINARY_DIR ${COMMON_BASE_PROJECT_DIR}/build
  STEP_TARGETS build
  EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL TRUE
)
...
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
include_directories(${COMMON_BASE_PROJECT_DIR}/include)
...
add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SRC_FILES} ${INCLUDE_FILES})
...
target_link_libraries (${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${COMMON_BASE_PROJECT_DIR}/build/libCommonBase.dll)
...
add_dependencies(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} CommonBaseProject-build)
```

I need to make a distribution which contains exe file and all library files.
I also need to package to that distribution qt libs which some of dependency project depend on:

```
find_package(Qt5Core ${QT_VERSION_REQ} REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Quick ${QT_VERSION_REQ} REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Widgets ${QT_VERSION_REQ} REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5DBus ${QT_VERSION_REQ} REQUIRED)
...
list(APPEND LIBS
    Qt5::Core
    Qt5::Quick
    Qt5::Widgets
    Qt5::DBus
)

target_link_libraries (${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${LIBS})
```

How to do that? I've tried cpack but there is a need to create a target for each of dll but that target is in lib project build files.

I will accept both cpack and non cpack solutions.

Comment: One workaround would place all your binaries and runtime libraries, with the desired path tree, and "zip" them.

Comment: How to know from cmake build file where qt dll located then?

Comment: [A manual](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html) with the information about cmake + qt[4/5].